# Travis-CI with: ERROR: Cannot find schemes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, continuous-integration, travis-ci

This is my `.travis.yml` file

```
language: objective-c

osx_image: xcode7.2

script: 
   xctool -project ProjectName.xcodeproj -scheme ProjectName build -sdk iphonesimulator
```

While Travis is running I've got this error:

> $ xctool -project ProjectName.xcodeproj -scheme ProjectName build -sdk iphonesimulator
>
> ERROR: Cannot find schemes. Please consider creating shared schemes in Xcode.
>
> TIP: This might happen if you're relying on Xcode to autocreate your schemes
> and your scheme files don't yet exist.  xctool, like xcodebuild, isn't able to
> automatically create schemes.  We recommend disabling "Autocreate schemes"
> in your workspace/project, making sure your existing schemes are marked as
> "Shared", and making sure they're checked into source control.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is easy to solve:

Go to your project scheme and click `Manage Schemes...`

[image]

Tick `Shared` for your scheme

[image]

Click `Close`, commit and push.

Problem Solved. Now Travis is working without problems.

[I also wrote a post in my blog about Travis-CI.](https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/05/add-travis-ci-to-your-coding-challenge/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by Gabriel.Massana, make sure the files are checked into version control (SVN/GIT).